# Can I use Gatsby and NEXT.JS together?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, gatsby

I want to use Gatsby and NEXT.JS in a project. Can I use Gatsby and NEXT.JS together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are web front-end frameworks with overlapping features. It is entirely possible to have some part of your application handled by Gatsby (SSG content) and some part with Next.js (SSR/CSR content). The recent versions of Next.js natively support SSG (Static Site Generation).

It is entirely your choice to use either one of these frameworks or a combination of both. Here is an excellent article comparing both frameworks: https://www.solutelabs.com/blog/gatsby-js-vs-next-js-which-one-to-choose-when

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know Gatsby and Next.js are two separate frameworks, and they are not designed to be used together in a single project. Each of these frameworks serves different purposes and has its own specific use cases. So the answer is you cannot use it together in single project.